# How can I post variables with next.js fetch?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to create a login page. Im trying to post some variables to my api but Im getting fetch error. Here is my codes.

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const req = await fetch('domain.com/api',{
   
      body: JSON.stringify({ id: 1 }),
      
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                 
      },
      method: 'POST'
    });
    const newData = await req.json();
    console.log(newData);
  };
```

api side:

```
function api_test(){
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('access-control-allow-origin: *');
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
  
  $this->db->where('id',$obj['id']);
  $query = $this->db->get('test')->row();
  
  echo json_encode($query);
   
}
```

when I just fetch url without post method and try to access id 1 manuelly. It works. Like:

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const req = await fetch('domain.com/api');
    const newData = await req.json();
    console.log(newData);
  };
```

api side:

```
  function api_test(){
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      header('access-control-allow-origin: *');
  
      
      $this->db->where('id',1);
      $query = $this->db->get('test')->row();
  
      echo json_encode($query);
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was because of cors. I allowed browser's cors with a Browser plugin and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).